# why cant i download react-codemirror2 onto my project folder in visual studio?

Tags: npm

npm i react-codemirror2
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined
npm ERR! Found: codemirror@6.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/codemirror
npm ERR!   codemirror@"^6.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer codemirror@"5.x" from react-codemirror2@7.2.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-codemirror2
npm ERR!   react-codemirror2@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\raksh\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-07-22T13_53_42_416Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\raksh\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-07-22T13_53_42_416Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\raksh> npm install codemirror@latest react-codemirror2@latest

> > 

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined
npm ERR! Found: codemirror@6.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/codemirror
npm ERR!   codemirror@"6.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer codemirror@"5.x" from react-codemirror2@7.2.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-codemirror2
npm ERR!   react-codemirror2@"7.2.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\raksh\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-07-22T13_57_34_327Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\raksh\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-07-22T13_57_34_327Z-debug-0.log
resolve this error

I tried npm i react-codemirror2 command